# css keyframes stops for a second aber every step

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm trying to rotate and scale something at the same time with keyframes, but I can't to get it correct without stopping after each step.

I tried it with font-size, but a smarter human being told me to change it to scale, but he won't help me.

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}

.plus {
    position: absolute;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;

    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: transform infinite 3s;
    transition: transform 3s ease;
}

@keyframes transform {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: scale(0.7) rotate(20deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.4);
    }
    75% {
        transform: scale(0.7) rotate(-20deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="plus">
    +
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not stopping, it's easing (slowing down at the end).
You don't need `transition: transform 3s ease;` and you don't want the "ease" for this animation.
You have to set it to linear: `animation-timing-function: linear;`
And yes, don't animate font-size :D